# When is a subspace of a Lie algebra a subalgebra?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras

Suppose we have a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with basis $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ and dual basis $\{\theta^1, \ldots, \theta^n\}$. Further suppose that $\mathfrak{h}\subset \mathfrak{g}$ is a codimension $\ell$ subspace given by $\mathfrak{h} = \text{span}\{\omega^1, \ldots, \omega^\ell\}^\perp$. Does the condition $d\omega^i \equiv 0 \mod \{\omega^1, \ldots, \omega^\ell\}$ imply that $\mathfrak{h}$ is a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$?

In particular, if $\mathfrak{h} = \text{span}\{\omega\}^\perp$, does $d\omega \wedge \omega = 0$ guarantee that $\mathfrak{h}$ will be a subalgebra?

Comment: **Hint** How would we write the integrability condition $d\omega^1 \equiv 0 \mod \{\omega^1, \ldots, \omega^l\}$ dually, in terms of Lie brackets?

Comment: Ah, I suppose I need to use $d\omega^1(e_j, e_k) = -\omega^1([e_j,e_k])  = -\omega^1(c^\ell_{jk}e_\ell) = - \delta^1_\ell c^\ell_{jk} = -c^1_{jk}$

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the whole idea---